# Wildcards in sql

Tags: sql, database, select

How does wildcards works in sql. If I do `select * from table` it give all the fields. But if I do `select a* from table` it gives error. Shouldn't it give all fields which begins with a?
I am little confused.

Comment: Nope.  That is not how it works.  The only rule is that `*` implies all the columns in a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM tableName` literally means "select all columns from tableName".

Philip Graham is right about his answer where he asked to use `a.*`

Wildcards help you search for strings about which you are not sure. These are almost always used with the `LIKE` keyword and put in `WHERE` clauses or searched `CASE` statements.

There are two wildcard characters - `%` and `_`.

`%` is used to find any string of 0 or more length.
E.g.,

```
SELECT firstName
  FROM persons
 WHERE UPPER(firstName) LIKE 'J%'
```

This will return all the `firstName` from the `persons` table where firstname starts with letter `J`. This would return "Jason", "James", "Josh", "Jessica" and much more.

Note that `UPPER` function was used to eliminate case sensitivity.

Next, you can have an `_` character that looks for the presence of one single character.

```
SELECT firstName
  FROM persons
 WHERE UPPER(firstName) LIKE 'J_M__'
```

This would return "James", "Jimmy", "Jamos", "Jxmx" and filter away any "Jason", "Jaguar", etc.

For more info click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/inter.815/a67843/cqspcl.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a.* where a is the name of the table. For instance in

```
select a.* from a left join b on a.id = b.id
```

You would return only the fields from a but not from b

Answer (score 3):

If want to use a wild card in SQL, You need to key on the column that you want to filter using `LIKE`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column_name LIKE 'a%';
```

This will give you everything that begins with 'a' on that column.

If you don't want all the columns, you must explicitly give the name of each column that you want in the query.

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, Address 
FROM table
```

So if you want all the fields that begin with 'a' you must name all the fields that begin with 'a' in the SELECT statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question!

Comment: @fastcodejava I was keying in on the "Wildcards in SQL" question not the reason for the question. I did alter the answer.